# I'm getting a NullPointerException in android , what's wrong with my code?

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I'm a java/android beginner. I get a NullPointerException when trying to run the below app. I want to get access points using getScanResults() but I get null when I don't use a thread so I used it. Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my code?Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btn;
WifiManager wifi;
final String TAG = "connectToWifi";
String[] wifis;
ListView list;
WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {

        btn.setText(R.string.on_label);
    } else {
        btn.setText(R.string.off_label);
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
            wifi.startScan();
        }

    }).start();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {

        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        btn.setText(R.string.off_label);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(wifi.getWifiState()));
        wifi.startScan();
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(wifi.getScanResults()));
        wifi.getScanResults();
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(wifi.getWifiState()));
        btn.setText(R.string.on_label);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(wifi.getWifiState()));

    }
}

class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        try {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
            }
        } finally {
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis));
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: `wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);` outside `Thread`

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now. But ScanResults() is still returning null.

Comment: @user4799681 You're implemented wrong way. You must add  `wifi.getScanResults();` in `onStart();` register your `BroadCast Reciever in Activity onStart();`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `wifi` before use it.

Make `wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);` before you first use wifi, that is `wifi.isWifiEnabled()`.

And also, pay attention to the logcat. It would tell you the exact reason why it happened.
Something like :

```
11-14 21:30:52.517: E/AndroidRuntime(18929): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 21:30:52.517: E/AndroidRuntime(18929): at com.kay.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
```